# Style binding options

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want a textbox which will always applied a Converter on the binding. this way I don't need to specified the converter, the style will already contains the converter to use.

This is what I already tried:

I have a ViewModel bound to view. I override the datacontext of a textbox within this view using a property of the view model. It allows me to use a generic style for my text box

I have the following Style:

```
<Style x:Key="DateTimeTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value ="40000"/>
    <Setter Property="Text" Value ="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource myConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/> 
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Unknown date format"/>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In the view I want to have the following text box bound on the porperty DateTimeValueToBind instead of the whole view model:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource DateTimeTextBox}" DataContext="{Binding DateTimeValueToBind}"/>
```

The property DateTimeValueToBind is displayed properly in the textbox however it's not bound anymore (when I modified it, the viewmodel property is not changed)

I tried to add the Mode=TwoWay in the binding options but It did not change anything.

Could explain why the DateTimeValueToBind property is not bound anymore in this context?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with with "not bound anymore; the viewmodel property is not changed"? If you modify the DataContext, the CLR property needs to raise that otherwise the UI will hold a reference to the old viewmodel. If you raise DataTimeValueToBind properly, it should automatically reraise the Text property. You can better understand how your bindings work by adding PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High to your Binding markups.

Comment: @dowhilefor: I don't modify the datacontext instance, I just want to delegate the binding to the textbox in order to use some generic binding options in my style (data converter) for this context. i could simply bind on the Text attribute but in this case I will alway need to specified the converter as well I want to put the convertion process in the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the `DataContext`, bind the `Text` to `DateTimeValueToBind` (move the binding from the `DataContext` to `Text`). You should never set such a binding in a style; if the path is `.` you *cannot* bind `TwoWay`. (And what did you save anyway? You even have more to write as `"DataContext"` is longer than `"Text"`.)

Comment: I understand and that what a usually do but in this case I don't know what the name of the property will be. in my application I have many dates to display (different property names) I want to applied a generic binding that will force the use of a specific converter and always specified it when binding it. how can i do that?

Comment: @gbr: You could create the binding programmatically once you know what you bind to.

Comment: in my previous commentI should have write "I want to applied a generic binding that will force the use of a specific converter and **NOT** always specified it when binding". To make thing short I want to "style" my binding options

Comment: @gbr: For that you could inherit from `Binding` and preset everything in the subclass. Stying bindings isn't really possible.